# Batch geocode addresses using a REST API (ArcPy, CSV, Server)

Tags: arcpy, csv, geocoding, arcgis-rest-api, rest

My stand-alone Python script tries to geocode a CSV file of addresses.
The script successfully geocodes this CSV file when using the *.loc file for this locator but not the published REST API.

ArcGIS Server is federated enterprise server (*not portal*) version 10.8.1, Python IDLE 3.7.9

Is there something wrong with this call to use the REST API?

```
arcpy.geocoding.GeocodeAddresses(r"M:\sample.csv",

                             r"https://mycity2.houstontx.gov/pubgis03/rest/services/LOCATORS/COH_ADDRESS_ROAD_LOCATOR/GeocodeServer",
                             "'Address or Place' Address VISIBLE NONE;Address2 <None> VISIBLE NONE;Address3 <None> VISIBLE NONE;Neighborhood <None> VISIBLE NONE;City <None> VISIBLE NONE;County <None> VISIBLE NONE;State <None> VISIBLE NONE;ZIP <None> VISIBLE NONE;ZIP4 <None> VISIBLE NONE;Country <None> VISIBLE NONE",
                             r"M:\BARCtest.gdb\sample5_GeocodeAddresses")
```

From a broswer, this REST API call works but it uses findAddressCandidates() to get results for just one address.
https://mycity2.houstontx.gov/pubgis03/rest/services/LOCATORS/COH_ADDRESS_ROAD_LOCATOR/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=pjson&SingleLine=1506%20Johnson%20ST

Error tracebacek from the arcpy.geocoding.GeocodeAddresses() call above.

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
**ERROR 000005: Could not open the address locator.**
Failed to execute (GeocodeAddresses).

Another approach I tried (unsuccessfully) was to use an ArcGIS Server connection file to access the locator.

```
arcpy.geocoding.GeocodeAddresses(r"M:\sample.csv",

                             r"C:\Users\arcgismanager.HOUTX\AppData\Roaming\Esri\ArcGISPro\Favorites\REST_services_on gisproarc04s_6443.ags/LOCATORS/COH_ADDRESS_ROAD_LOCATOR/GeocodeServer",
                             "'Address or Place' Address VISIBLE NONE;Address2 <None> VISIBLE NONE;Address3 <None> VISIBLE NONE;Neighborhood <None> VISIBLE NONE;City <None> VISIBLE NONE;County <None> VISIBLE NONE;State <None> VISIBLE NONE;ZIP <None> VISIBLE NONE;ZIP4 <None> VISIBLE NONE;Country <None> VISIBLE NONE",
                             r"M:\BARCtest.gdb\sample5_GeocodeAddresses")
```

This gives the following error.

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
**ERROR 000732: Input Address Locator: Dataset** C:\Users\arcgismanager.HOUTX\AppData\Roaming\Esri\ArcGISPro\Favorites\REST_services_on gisproarc04s_6443.ags/LOCATORS/COH_ADDRESS_ROAD_LOCATOR/GeocodeServer **does not exist or is not supported**
ERROR 000005: Could not open the address locator.
Failed to execute (GeocodeAddresses).

[ESRI Technical Support](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010565)

This ESRI document talks about an ArcGIS Online locator which I'm not using. It also mentions a composite locator. I was using a composite locator but I switched to a non-composite and still got the same error message.